# jQuery Waypoints - All Elements FadeIn At Once Rather Than OnScroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I'm a newb to this, but I am using jQuery Waypoint and I'm trying to get elements to "fadeIn" when scrolled into view. The problem that I'm having is that when the first element is scrolled into view, all elements fadeIn. That means you only see the first element fadeIn on scroll. The rest fadeIn outside the viewport.

I don't understand how to make each element fadeIn when scrolled into viewport. Rather than all elements fadeIn at once...

Here is my code:

```
      $(window).scroll(function () {
          $("#top-section").waypoint(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(750); },{ offset: '10px' });
          $("#upper-section").waypoint(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(750); },{ offset: '10px' });
          $("#home-main").waypoint(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(750); },{ offset: '10px' });
          $("#home-sidebar-wrapper").waypoint(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(750); },{ offset: '10px' });
          $("#lower-section").waypoint(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(750); },{ offset: '10px' });
          $("#bottom-section").waypoint(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(750); },{ offset: '10px' });
          $("#static-section").waypoint(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(750); },{ offset: '10px' });
          $("#footer-section-1").waypoint(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(750); },{ offset: '10px' });
          $("#footer-section-2").waypoint(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(750); },{ offset: '10px' });
          $("#footer-section-3").waypoint(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(750); },{ offset: '10px' });
          $("#footer-section-4").waypoint(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(750); },{ offset: '10px' });
          $("#footer-section-5").waypoint(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(750); },{ offset: '10px' });
      });
```

**EDIT**: by request, here is an alternate jsFiddle for helping debug: http://jsfiddle.net/tUW8k/

Comment: remove $(window).scroll(function(){ and });

Comment: @carter when I do that, then all elements are already loaded. I don't see a fadeIn, but the `style="display:block"` is in each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements with display none do not live anywhere in the document. They report themselves as living at 0,0 coordinates on the page. Do not use display none elements as waypoints. Instead, animate opacity from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 0):

get a fiddle going, show some css as well.  your .waypoint() function should only execute when your selection becomes visible by being scrolled to.  You are sure your css is starting with display:none; for those elements?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive they are set to 'display: none;' within the CSS. the script is getting fired because it shows `style="display:block"` inline the elements. It's just not giving the desired effect of the fadeIn when scrolled to. I will try to make a fiddle...